# How can I set current URL's and track names in M4A (AAC) songs?

Tags: music, aac

I was listening to a [mixset from Moby](http://www.xlr8r.com/podcast/2010/06/moby) in iTunes today and noticed a few cool things about this M4A file which I would really like to know how to do on my own.

1. The file has some type of embedded URL, so that in the "Now Playing" window, there is a nice little link to Moby's webpage.
2. The file also has album art which changes for the current track in the mix, and it updates iTunes' status panel to show the track artist and name.
3. None of this stuff seems to be visible anywhere in the "Get Info" section of the track.

How can I make my M4A mixes do this?  Is there some sort of special utility that I need for this?